# How to have a fluid flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors, styles

I am trying to make a fluid flex field where if there is no enough space then it should drop to next line. As you can see in this [example](https://codepen.io/k-hamid/pen/oNWmEjv) if you decrease the size of the field it doesnt drop to next line because I am using flex.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .panel {
  flex: none;
}
.container .panel-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.container .panel-info .dot {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel">Some Long Info</div>
  <div class="panel-info">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="info">Information</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex-wrap: wrap`.

[More information on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) about the `flex-wrap` property